# URL sent in window.open(url), opens a new window but ulr is modified with encryption and with source=proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a `ulr` as defined below
`https://some_site/personal/abcd/Documents/Microsoft%20Teams%20Chat%20Files/play%20games.docx!sp_id=1557631223`.

When I pass this windows open function, like below

`const win = window.open(url, '_blank');`

a seperate window opens but the navigation says, (did not type complete url)
Navigated to `https://some_site/_forms/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fpersonal%2fabcd%2games.252Edocx%2521sp%255Fid%253D1557631223&Source=cookie`.

Why did this happen?
like `_` (underscore in `sp_id` of main `url`) is replaced with `%255F` and complete `url` is appended with `Source=cookie`.

Need help.

Comment: This does not look to be a javascript problem, rather the url you're trying to access is redirecting you to somewhere else when you try to access it, most likely to a login form. It has encoded the _ in sp_id but that is also a red herring, it's just preparing to redirect back to your original url once the form action is complete.

Comment: Thanks Nevelina A. It gives me a hint. Thanks for explanation again. I am very new to web technology. I will try to see why and how it is redirected. Again, any help in this regards is appreciated.